# Liferay with PrimeFaces, display image -NOT using Path -

Tags: image, jsf, primefaces, liferay, liferay-6

I'm developing a Liferay Portlet, using primeFaces. Several pages will feature DataTable elements, where one of the columns will have an image thumbnail.

How can you present an image with PF components, if you can't use image path ? 
Searching the tutorials and the available PF controls, I see components like , that loads an image stored in the Tomcat directory, using it's relative path as value.

But what happens if you like to take an image stored with Documents And Media, or in a remote Database as a Blob/bytearray/Text ?

How would you suggest me to load the images in a DataTable column?

Using Primefaces 3.5 and Liferay 6.1.0 ce ga1
Thank you..

Comment: You can use `<p:graphicImage value="#{bean.imageStream}"/>`, with `imageStream` you can get from database or `Documents And Media` via servicebuilder.

Comment: @RongNK: please note that OP is using Liferay, which is a Portlet environment, not a Servlet environment.

Comment: @BalusC: yes, i am using Liferay :)

Comment: @RongNK thanx for your input, I think that covers my question. You're welcome to rewrite your comment as answer for better visibility

Comment: @yannicuLar i will post at tonight, when i come home :)